# ng-mocks error: MockBuilder/test.deep.spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, ng-mocks

I simply the ng-mocks module like I have to previous projects but today I am getting the following error.:

```
Firefox 78.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js):
  Error: ....node_modules/ng-mocks/examples/MockBuilder/test.deep.spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
  The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the Angular Package Format .
```

Comment: Hi, might you post your `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

in your `tsconfig.json` you need to exclude `node_modules`.

```
{
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
}
```